# Error while create customer attribute : Wrong attribute group ID

Tags: magento2.2.6

I am creating customer attribute but getting error run while setup upgrade command

```
Wrong attribute group ID
```

here is my code for create customer attribute

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\CustomerFeedBack\Setup;
use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetup;
use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\UpgradeDataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;
use Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerMetadataInterface;
use Magento\Customer\Setup\CustomerSetupFactory;
/**
 * @codeCoverageIgnore
 */
class UpgradeData implements UpgradeDataInterface
{
    /**
     * EAV setup factory
     *
     * @var EavSetupFactory
     */
    private $eavSetupFactory;
    private $eavConfig;
    private $customerSetupFactory;
    /**
     * Init
     *
     * @param EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory
     */
    public function __construct(EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory,\Magento\Eav\Model\Config $eavConfig,CustomerSetupFactory $customerSetupFactory){
        $this->eavSetupFactory = $eavSetupFactory;
        $this->eavConfig       = $eavConfig;
        $this->customerSetupFactory = $customerSetupFactory;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.ExcessiveMethodLength)
     */
    public function upgrade(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context){
        /** @var EavSetup $eavSetup */
        $eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);
        if (version_compare($context->getVersion(), '1.0.1') < 0) {
            $customerSetup = $this->customerSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);
            $customerSetup->addAttribute(\Magento\Customer\Model\Customer::ENTITY, 'customer_feedback', [
                'label' => 'Referral Sources',
                'input' => 'text',
                'type' => 'varchar',
                'source' => '',
                'required' => false,
                'position' => 0,
                'visible' => true,
                'system' => false,
                'is_used_in_grid' => true,
                'is_visible_in_grid' => true,
                'is_filterable_in_grid' => true,
                'is_searchable_in_grid' => true,
                'backend' => ''
            ]);
            $attribute = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getAttribute('customer', 'customer_feedback')
                ->addData(['used_in_forms' => [
                    'adminhtml_customer'
                ]]);
            $attribute->save();
        }
    }
}
```

can anyone help me with same...

Magento version 2.2.6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can give a try to below code,

```
<?php
namespace LazyCoder\UploadDocument\Setup;

use Magento\Customer\Model\Customer;
use Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Set as AttributeSet;
use Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\SetFactory as AttributeSetFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\UpgradeDataInterface;

class UpgradeData implements UpgradeDataInterface
{
    private $customerSetupFactory;

    public function __construct(\Magento\Customer\Setup\CustomerSetupFactory $customerSetupFactory, AttributeSetFactory $attributeSetFactory)
    {
        $this->customerSetupFactory = $customerSetupFactory;
        $this->attributeSetFactory = $attributeSetFactory;
    }
    public function upgrade(
        ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup,
                            ModuleContextInterface $context
    ) {
        if (version_compare($context->getVersion(), '1.1.2') < 0) {
            $customerSetup = $this->customerSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);
            $setup->startSetup();
            $attributesInfo = [
                'customer_number' => [
                    'label' => 'Customer Number',
                    'type' => 'varchar',
                    'input' => 'text',
                    'position' => 1030,
                    'visible' => true,
                    'required' => false,
                    'system' => 0,
                    'user_defined' => true,
                    'position' => 1030,
                    'is_used_in_grid' => true,
                    'is_visible_in_grid' => true,
                    'is_html_allowed_on_front' => true,
                    'visible_on_front' => true
                ]
            ];
            $customerEntity = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getEntityType('customer');
            $attributeSetId = $customerEntity->getDefaultAttributeSetId();
            /** @var $attributeSet AttributeSet */
            $attributeSet = $this->attributeSetFactory->create();
            $attributeGroupId = $attributeSet->getDefaultGroupId($attributeSetId);
            foreach ($attributesInfo as $attributeCode => $attributeParams) {
                $customerSetup->addAttribute(Customer::ENTITY, $attributeCode, $attributeParams);
            }
            $magentoUsernameAttribute = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getAttribute(Customer::ENTITY, 'customer_number');
            $magentoUsernameAttribute->addData([
                'attribute_set_id' => $attributeSetId,
                'attribute_group_id' => $attributeGroupId,
                'used_in_forms' => ['adminhtml_customer','customer_account_edit','adminhtml_checkout','adminhtml_customer_address','customer_address_edit','customer_register_address'],
            ]);
            $magentoUsernameAttribute->save();


        }
        $setup->endSetup();
    }
}
```

Comment: attribute created but value are not saving...

Comment: Where you trying to save ? At backend or from frontend ?

Comment: At backend , From  customer edit

Comment: Are you getting any error ? Please check logs.

Comment: not getting any error just value are not saved that's the issue

Comment: Strange Its tested code and I'm using it. Give a try to change attribute code.I mean create new attribute. May be your db is corrupt. Try with fresh installation.

Comment: also try same ... delete attribute create again same error

Comment: Bad luck :( Thre's something wrong with your DB othetwise it will work. You have to look for it.

Answer (score 1):

try to add group key in array and provide name of the group of attribute

```
  'group' => 'Test Group',
```

Comment: This resolved the issue for me. Thank you!

Comment: Most Welcome... :)